# Arithmetic overflow in psscaleboxto

Tags: pstricks, scaling

The following example, using `\psscaleboxto`, produces an error:

> "I can't carry out that multiplication or division, since the result is out of range."

Why does it happen?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(20,20)
\psscaleboxto(1,1) {
  \psframe(0,0)(5,5)
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that cannot work, because all PSTricks objects have inside TeX a width and height of 0pt. That is the reason why you can't  expand "nothing" to 1x1. This will work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](10,10)
\psscaleboxto(1,1){\rule{5cm}{5cm}}
\psframe*[unit=0.2,linecolor=red](5,5)(10,10)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

`\rule` is known with width and height on TeX level.

[image]

You can use the default `\resizebox` or `\psscalebox` if you have a `pspicture` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\resizebox{4cm}{2cm}{%
  \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](10,10)
  \psframe*[linecolor=red](5,5)(10,10)
  \psdot[dotstyle=x,dotscale=5](3,3)
  \end{pspicture}%
}
\qquad
\psscaleboxto(2,4){%
  \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](10,10)
  \psframe*[linecolor=red](5,5)(10,10)
  \psdot[dotstyle=x,dotscale=5](3,3)
  \end{pspicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see that putting the psframe inside the scalebox also works, as long as the \rule is there:  "\psscaleboxto(1,1){
 \rule{5cm}{5cm}
 \psframe*[linecolor=red](5,5)(10,10)
}"

Is there a way to make the black "rule" disappear?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? With the options `xunit=..,yunit=..` you can do the same with objects.

Comment: I have not a single object but an arrangement of several objects (frames, dots, etc), and I want to reproduce the same arrangement in a smaller scale, in order to illustrate some recursive construction (similar to a fractal).

Comment: see my edit ...

Comment: I see, so I just have to put the pspicture inside the psscalebox.